# PostgreSQL claims to support 170 of 179 SQL:2016 features, but it also lists 309 features of SQL:2016 that it doesn't support. Why the discrepancy?

Tags: postgresql, sql-standard

As of September 2020, PostgreSQL claims to support most of the SQL:2016 standard, but the numbers in don't match up at all. [From PostgreSQL's documentation:](https://www.postgresql.org/about/)

> As of the version 13 release in September 2020, PostgreSQL conforms to at least **170 of the 179** mandatory features for SQL:2016 Core conformance.
> (emphasis mine)

So 9 features are unsupported. But elsewhere, PostgreSQL lists [all the features of SQL:2016 that it *doesn't* support](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/unsupported-features-sql-standard.html), and there's **309** features listed. This is more unsupported features than the first page claimed even *exist* in SQL:2016. Granted, some of the unsupported features are irrelevant, like "Embedded Ada" or "Module Language COBOL", but either way, there's way more than 9 unsupported features listed here. And I don't think that SQL:2016 changed so much (or even at all) between 2020 and 2021, so that can't be the reason for the mismatch.

I thought that individual unsupported features might be grouped together into 9 "features" somehow, e.g. all features involving support for dead languages are counted as one feature, and all XML-related features are counted as one feature, etc., but after skimming through the list of 309 unsupported features, I don't see any clear way to do this.

So, why the discrepancy? Is it because of individual features being grouped together, or is it something else?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Features in the SQL standard are split between mandatory features and optional features.

As stated [here](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/features.html)

> Out of 177 **mandatory** features required for full Core conformance, PostgreSQL conforms to at least 170. In addition, there is a long list of supported **optional** features

<sup>(emphasis mine)</sup>

So the discrepancy you are seeing, stems from the difference between mandatory and optional features.